# is ther any way I can breakpoint a whole project in visual studio?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019

I just need to find a certain location that a value is being set and I think the best way would be to somehow run through the whole project as it does with a breakpoint instead of trying to just find it. this is visual studio 2019 btw.

Comment: Per your exact question, you can possibly set a breakpoint on your entry point and single-step through there.  But you're probably better off using a data breakpoint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224031/how-get-a-breakpoint-on-variable-write-in-visual-studio

Comment: the thing is I have no idea what the type is or the name or where it even might be I don't know where to set the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is using .NET, you may try my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) extension that can show your the first method called in your project .dll.