# Member variables being re-initialised after MessageBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, class, member-variables

I have a `Form` which has code similar to this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int m_var1;
    private int m_var2;
    string sMsg;
    bool bReturn;

    private bool MyFunction()
    {
        // POINT A: at this point m_var1 and m_var2 are both 100            
        sMsg = "Test Message";
        bReturn = (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show(sMsg, "MyApp",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question));
        // POINT B: at this point m_var1 and m_var2 are both 0
    }
}
```

Why at `POINT B` have `m_var1` and `m_var2` both changed to `0` as I am experiencing?

Comment: Please provide a small but complete sample project that reproduces this problem. This is no normal behavior and your question doesn't contain enough information to answer it.

Comment: Are the variables' values by any chance influenced by another thread?

Comment: Please give the code where your assigning the values to m_var1 and m_var2 or add full function code(MyFunction)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: that is not feasible at the moment. Is there some way I can debug what is happening at the `MessageBox.Show` line?

Comment: @CJ7: `MessageBox.Show` surely has nothing to do with this phenomen.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: well then what is it then?  It happens only after that line. It cannot be anything other than something that happens between Point A and Point B.

Comment: @CJ7: `MessageBox.Show` doesn't change your variables. Period. That's why I was asking for more code. You might have a thread that manipulates some data, but it really is impossible to say.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: can I have a debugger running in the background to see what is happening?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: using Carra's answer below I was able to find out that the Form.Activated event was resetting the variables. The MessageBox was causing the form to activate again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a thread issue. I can explain how I would try to solve this problem:

- Change m_var1 and m_var2 to Properties.
- Set a breakpoint to their setters.

Check the stacktrace of the code that hit the setter.

Comment: in visual studio you can have the debugger stop when any symbol is assigned a value. Ie you can set a break point when m_var1 is assigned, so you don't technically need to change them to properties

Comment: @CJ7 sorry won't help you since it doesn't work for managed code at least not according to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160045/visual-studio-debugger-break-when-a-value-changes